# I have a LUA Garry's Mod error and I can't solve it

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

I get this error and I do not know what is wrong, I already searched in google and I do not get answers about what could happen someone,

```
MENU ERROR] lua/menu/mainmenu.lua:84: attempt to call field 'IsCurrentServerFavorite' (a nil value)
  1. unknown - lua/menu/mainmenu.lua:84 (x5830)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the file `mainmenu.lua` line 84 you do something like:

`someTable.IsCurrentServerFavorite()` or `someTable:IsCurrentServerFavorite` where the table does not have a field named `IsCurrentServerFavorite`. Hence this value is nil and you may not call it as if it were a function.

To get rid of that error either don't call that or make sure you only do it with the correct table that actually has a function like `IsCurrentServerFavorite`